# How to install .crt and .key file in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I have two files called `.crt` and `.key`

I need to install these in Tomcat server with running on port 8443.

How to do that?

Comment: Why do you know that you need to do it in the tomcat?

Comment: since there's a java application I just need it to run on Tomcat.

Comment: Have you at least googled for "tomcat SSL configuration"?

Comment: Yes I googled but couldn't find something clear and simple.